# What does $\sup _n$ mean?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

I came across this notation when studying about the Kolmogorov Convergence Criterion, namely

Suppose that $\sup _n |X_n| \leq A$ for some $A>0$, ...

I understand what does $\sup$ mean, but what does $\sup_n$ mean?

I have tried to search for more information online but did not manage to find anything.

Comment: Is there supposed to be anything between the $\sup_n$ and the $\leq$?

Comment: @Arthur edited. Thanks!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen how is that relevant?

Answer (score 3):

It means the supremum of the possible values of $|X_n|$ as you vary $n$ (presumably in the domain of $X_n$).

Answer (score 0):

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, which is bounded from above, then let $A:=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...\}$.

By definition we have

$$\sup_n a_n= \sup A.$$